# Vtiger migration from 6.0 to 6.1

Tags: migration, vtiger

I have followed the instructions on this link http://community.vtiger.com/help/vtigercrm/administrators/migration.html to migrate from 6.0 to 6.1 .
When i insert the link http://yourserver.tld/migrate i receive the message : WARNING : Cannot continue with Migration
We detected that this source is upgraded latest version.

But obviosly i don't have 6.1 already. I suppose there is something strange in the directories of zip.
Anyone can help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you must download the File vtigercrm-600-610-patch.zip from here http://sourceforge.net/projects/vtigercrm/files/vtiger%20CRM%206.1.0/Core%20Product/ and then unzip this in your vTiger 6.0 directory. After that go to your vTiger url and add migation/ to start the migration

for example:

http: // yourvtigerurl.de/migration/